# Calculating summary statistics and access resulting value in table using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, table, statistics

With arcpy, I want to calculate the mean value of a specific field in a shapefile and print the resulting value for the user. 
I use the Summary Statistics tool and it works, but the resulting value is stored in a table at a specific path, but how can I access the calculated value with python?

Here is my code. It will only output the path to the table, but I need the calculated value.

```
stats = arcpy.Statistics_analysis(myshapefile, "G:/temp/stats", [[field, "MEAN"]])
arcpy.AddMessage(stats.getOutput(0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would recommend to access the contents of a table is by using [arcpy.da.SearchCursor()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/SearchCursor/018w00000011000000/) to read it:

> SearchCursor establishes read-only access to the records returned from
>   a feature class or table.
>
> Returns an iterator of tuples. The order of values in the tuple
>   matches the order of fields specified by the field_names argument

The asker also:

> found a useful function on this website:
>   https://arcpy.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/calculate-a-mean-value-from-a-field/

which groups the Summary Statistics with a Search Cursor to read its output and return the Mean value from a field.